# UIAppearance not updated when popping a view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiappearance

UINavigationBar UIAppearance doesn't update when popping from a pushed view controller. But it does when dismissing from a modal view controller. Is that the normal behaviour? Is there a way to update it when only popping from a pushed view controller?

Comment: can you show you code to debbug it and help you

Comment: There's nothing much to see. I just modify UIAppearance in a view controller then: if I dismiss it (it was modal) the appearance doesn't update, if I pop it (it was pushed) the appearance updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do as follow:

```
let windows = UIApplication.shared.windows
for window in windows {
    for view in window.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        window.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```